# Render view from another controller with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, nested-form-for

I have code in my **products_controller.rb**

```
        def create
          @product = Product.new(product_params)
          brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
          @product.brand = brand

          if @product.save
            raise "OK"
          else
            @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
            render 'brands/show'
          end
        end
```

After failure of save method, i need to redirect to brands **show.html.erb** view, which find brand by id and display information about it.

**Questions:**

1. Is it right way of doing that
2. If user manually passed server_id parameter, how can prevent it from executing (SQL injection)? Or how should i check and display error?
3. How can i display errors in `brands/show` views outside form ( because i'm storing form in `<a data-form="...">` property, so user can't see form until he clicks on link. Even more, i use `form_for([@brand,@brand.send(:products).klass.new])`)

Comment: Usually, you use render within the same controller, when you want to show error messages on the model that you tried and failed to update. Now it's totally fine to use it cross-controllers, as long as you declare the same instance variables used in the other controller action.
However beware, of the URL that will be displayed in the browser ! Using redirect_to will force the URL to change, render won't

Answer (score 2):

use redirect_to brands_path(@brand)

Comment: Ok, now it displays view. But ` redirect_to brands_path(@brand) ` as i understand passes only brand if as GET parameter, not the whole instance variable ( raise @brand.inspect says that it is nil ). And second - my errors storing in @product.errors (as you see from controller code), so i tried write something like ` redirect_to brands_path(@brand, @product) `, but when i try to catch @brand or @product in my `brand/show` action - it is nil.

Comment: use redirect_to brands_path(brand: @brand, product: @product) and in brand show controller use params[:brand] and params[:product] to get these values.

Comment: Look, i just try to do something like
`flash[:errors] = @product.errors
    redirect_to server_path(@brand)`
And it works. Just use `flash.errors.each` to display errors in view. Maybe it is a better way of doing that?

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you. So can i use my method with flash[:errors]? Is it okay for best practices?

Comment: sure , flash keep the message till next action so when you redirect to show page flash errors shows there.